# Wordpress custom API development

Tags: wordpress, api

Below is the code I am using

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'add_custom_users_api');

function add_custom_users_api(){
   register_rest_route( 'testing', '/users', array(
     'methods' => 'GET',
     'callback' => 'get_custom_users_data',
   ));
}

function get_custom_users_data($data){
    //get users by market
    $result = "Testing this";
    return $result;
}
```

Below is the response I am getting

[image]

Comment: check this https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_route/

Comment: Thanks for the link. very useful. Can you also please tell me if I do not create any namespace then?

Comment: namespace for version controller. Are you using version in API?

Comment: no, I am creating a test API. I have updated my question. Please help

Comment: you can use simply like `register_rest_route( 'testapi', '/apiendpoint', array(
            'methods' => 'POST',
            'callback' => 'callback_function'
        ));`

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'add_custom_users_api');

function add_custom_users_api(){
    register_rest_route( 'testing', '/users', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'get_custom_users_data',
    ));
}

function get_custom_users_data($data){
    //get users by market
    $result = "Testing this";
    return $result;
}
```

http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/testing/users

[image]

Comment: It says {"code":"rest_no_route","message":"No route was found matching the URL and request method","data":{"status":404}}

Comment: updated my answer. your project folder is wordpress. right?

Comment: No. I didnt change anything.

Comment: I have added an image in my question

Comment: why you are adding index.php in API endpoint. remove that and try

Comment: Have removed that but no luck

Comment: your project folder is wordpress?

Comment: Its BigFM so I am using http://localhost/BigFM/wp-json/testing/users and http://localhost/BigFM/index.php/wp-json/testing/users both

Comment: Are you using any plugin? and wordpress version?

Comment: WP REST API I was using but deactivated Wordpress version 4.8.3

Comment: if you can send me functions.php file